# sublime plugin development region intersect

Tags: sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I want to determine if two regions intersect.
The documentation refers to two functions which will do this I think:
intersection(region) : Returns the set intersection of the two regions
intersects(region)   : Returns True iff this == region or both include one or more positions in common

What is the syntax for using these functions?

Comment: if your two regions are in variables named `region1` and `region2`, then `region1.intersects(region2)`; a `Region` is a class with methods and properties.

Comment: Thanks for that.